# PHPに関する質問です。（オーバーライド）

Tags: php

PHPに関する質問です。
以下のコードですが、結果としては、3パーセント割引された商品価格が$priceに入るという結果を期待しているのですが、親クラスのgetPriceメソッドが呼び出されていないようです。
なぜでしょうか？詳しい方、ご教示ください。
参考：http://www.objective-php.net/basic/override

```
class Product
{
    protected $price;
    protected $discountRate = 0.03;

    public function getPrice()
    {
        $price = $this->price - ($this->price * $this->discountRate);
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}

class FoodProduct extends Product
{
    private $expire = 15;

    public function getExpire()
    {
        return $this->expire;
    }

    public function decrementExpire()
    {
        $this->expire--;
        return $this->getExpire();
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        $price = parent::getPrice();

        if($this->expire <= 10){
            $price = $price / 2;
        }
        return $price;
    }
}


$prd = new FoodProduct();

$prd->setPrice(100);

$expire = $prd->getExpire();

while($expire > 0){
    echo '賞味期限:'.$expire . '日 価格：'.$prd->getPrice().'<br>';
    $expire = $prd->decrementExpire();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ProductクラスのgetPriceメソッドの

```
return $this->price;
```

を

```
return $price
```

にすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: それだと期限切れ近いものは3%引きの半値ですね。
どうしたいのか書いていないので何とも言えないのですが、定価の半値が求めるものであるように思えます。
基底で値引きを入れる構造に無理があるように思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下のようにするといいのではないでしょうか？
※訂正前の内容と、間違えている内容をコード内にコメントで記載しています

```
class Product
{
    protected $price;
    protected $discountRate = 0.03;

    public function getPrice()
    {
        $price = $this->price - ($this->price * $this->discountRate);
        return $price;
        //return $this->price;   //元の価格を戻り値として返しちゃってます
    }

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}
```